# How can I get a Spring REST file download to return 404?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, filesystems

I have a simple REST API, with file download capability. The endpoint is defined like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myapi/files/{fileName}", 
    method = RequestMethod.GET, 
    produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE })
@ResponseBody FileSystemResource downloadFile(String fileName) 
    throws UnknownFileException;
```

The meat of the implementation method is currently:

```
try {
    FileSystemResource fsr = 
        new FileSystemResource("C:/myfiles/" + fileName + "." + suffix);
} catch (Throwable e) {
    throw new UnknownFileException();
}
```

And I have a simple exception handler, which returns a 404.

```
@ExceptionHandler(UnknownFileException.class)
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public ErrorMessage handleUnknownFileException(
        UnknownFileException e, HttpServletRequest req) {
    return new ErrorMessage(e);
}
```

These exception handlers work nicely for other operations which return XML/JSON responses. The trouble I have is that when this method throws an exception, it looks like it's being intercepted by the Spring ResourceHttpMessageConverter, which is throwing a 500 error back to the client.

So my question is how I might ensure that an HTTP 404 is returned instead of the generic 500?

Edit - Stack trace below for what it's worth:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is com.....UnknownFileException: Unable to find file
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:88)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

Comment: As a note, it's a bad idea to either catch `Throwable` or to name an exception `Error`. `Error`s are major VM or hardware errors, and you can't appropriately handle them in the middle of your code; calling your own exception class `Error` is asking for confusion.

Comment: Is the `Error` class your own? Or the JDK's?

Comment: That Error class is not an Exception. It's my own little model object with XML/JSON annotations. From my experience it's a very bad idea to *not* catch Throwable in web services, as I need to control the response in all situations.

Comment: @Steve Have you imported it at the top of your class?

Comment: I have - there are a number of other methods in the same class, some of which throw that exception successfully in order to generate 404s. The only problem is when the return object is a FileSystemResource.

Comment: In case anybody new is wondering about previous questions, I have renamed the Error response object to ErrorMessage in the code above to avoid confusion about what it might be.

Comment: Not that it's an answer, but I typically try to catch all "expected" errors in the controller and then use the "org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity" to wrap the response. That way, I can explicitly state the kind of http response code I want to send to the client depending on what happened in the implementation of the controller method.

Comment: It sounds like it could be an answer to me ... I'll see what happens if I change the return type to be ResponseEntity and then within the controller make the choice between binary download and 404. Using it within @ControllerAdvice would be even nicer, but I seem to be unable to get my app working on Spring 3.2 so far. :-/

Comment: Where is your `@ExceptionHandler` relative to the code that throws the exception? And what Spring version are you on?

Comment: The @ExceptionHandler is in the controller. It's currently using Spring 3.1.4.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do something like this:

```
response.setStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
```

Of course, you would need to add the HttpServletResponse to the method declaration.